# Expression for $\arccos\frac2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Are there any 'nice' expressions for

$$\arccos\frac2\pi$$

By 'nice', I mean involving rationals, square roots, powers of $\pi$, etc... I'm hoping there is something that doesn't involve sum or product series, nested radicals, continued fractions, integrals, derivatives, etc...

I'm aware of the Taylor series expansion for $\arccos$:

$$\arccos x=\frac\pi2-\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(2k)!x^{2k+1}}{2^{2k}(k!)^2(2k+1)}}$$

which for $x=\frac2\pi$ becomes

$$\arccos\frac2\pi=\frac\pi2-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(2k)!}{\pi^{2k+1}(k!)^2(2k+1)}}$$

Does the sum in this case converge to a 'nice' expression?

Comment: I believe it is not difficult to prove (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) that $\pi$ and $\arccos\frac{2}{\pi}$ are algebraically independent, hence the answer to your question is simply *no*.

Comment: You may be correct. However, can the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem be used for the proof since $\pi$ is transcendental?